# How to find the positive index of element [-1] in Python list

Tags: python, arrays, list

How can I find the positive index of `myList[-1]`?
This is an example of what I want:

Input:

```py
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3]
# Please keep in mind that the list can have multiple values that are the same

myIndex = # Find out the positive index of myList[-1] and store in myIndex variable
print(myIndex)
```

Desired Output:

```
4
```

Comment: It’s just `len(myList) - 1`

Comment: The index of the last element is just the number of elements in your list so myIndex = len(list)

Comment: No @Edo98 the index of last element it's actually len(myList) - 1, as MarkMeyer said.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is:

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3]
index = len(myList) - 1
```

You might want to check if it is greater or equal to zero.

Comment: Haha sorry! I feel like an idiot

Comment: @Serket: No worries. Happens to the best of us...